# OpenGL, как рисовать по координатам окна?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glfw

Я хочу изучить OpenGL, сейчас столкнулся с такой проблемой....
дело в том что рисование происходит по таким координатам:

```
GLfloat vertices [] {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f
    };
```

И не понятно как рисовать, по каким то процентным соотношениям, я знаю что можно производить рисование, по координатам окна, то есть по пикселям.. ну лево это 0 по ширине, право это макс. переменной WIDTH... так же и по высоте, 0 это в низу а в верху это максимальное значение переменной HEIGTH
Что вписать в этом коде что бы поменять систему координат для рисования?

```
#include <iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

GLfloat vertices [] {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f
};

const GLint WIDTH = 640, HEIGTH = 480;

const GLchar *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
"}";



const GLchar *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"void main () \n"
"{\n"
"color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
"}";



int main () {
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow (WIDTH, HEIGTH, "Learn OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize (window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);

    if (nullptr == window) {
        cout<<"Failed to create GLFW window"<<endl;
        glfwTerminate ();

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()) {
        cout<<"Failed to initialize GLEW"<<endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }

    glViewport (0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);



    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource (vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL );
    glCompileShader (vertexShader);
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];

    glGetShaderiv (vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog (vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout<<"ERROR::SHADER::COMPILATION_FAILED"<<infoLog<<endl;
    }
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource (fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader (fragmentShader);
    glGetShaderiv (fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog (fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout<<"ERROR::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED"<<infoLog<<endl;
    }
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram ();
    glAttachShader (shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader (shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram (shaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv (shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog (shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        cout<<"ERROR::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED"<<infoLog<<endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader (vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader (fragmentShader);

    GLuint VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays (1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers (1, &VBO);
    glBindVertexArray (VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof (GLfloat), (GLvoid *) 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray (0);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        glUseProgram ( shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray ( VAO );
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray (0);

        glfwSwapBuffers (window);
    }
    glDeleteVertexArrays (1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers (1, &VBO);

    glfwTerminate ();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: что Вы хотите нарисовать, прямоугольник на весь экран?

Comment: не знаю поняли ли вы меня... 
так рисовать не удобно! и не понятно!
GLfloat vertices [] {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f
    };
было бы удобнее рисовать треугольник так
GLfloat vertices [] {
        100.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f,
        150.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f,
        50.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f
    };
как бы по "пикселям"
раньше я так рисовал, без использования шейдеров!

Comment: можете задавать вершины как там удобно, а потом пересчитать в диапазон `[-1,1]`

Comment: как то так `"gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0)/100.0 - vec4(0.5,0.5,0.0,0.0);\n"`

Comment: а вы не знаете почему вот эта часть кода не работает? как я понял она именно для этого чего я хочу:
glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, screenWidth, screenHeigth);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    glOrtho (0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 1000);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    void glOrtho (GLdouble left, GLdouble right, GLdouble bottom, GLdouble top,
                  GLdouble near, GLdouble far);

Comment: код начинает работать если использовать просто GLFW c некоторыми функциями gl

Comment: я не понимаю этот диапазон для чего он нужен? разве с ним удобно работать?

Comment: вы еще ничего не вращали, раз так говорите =)

Comment: когда 0 по центру экрана удобнее считать, хотя это мб субъективно =)

Comment: `glMatrixMode` - это для фиксированного конвейера, а вам надо самостоятельно построить матрицу преобразования оконных координат, отправить ее в константный буфер на GPU чтобы она стала видна в шейдере и затем внутри вершинного шейдера умножать на нее оконные координаты вершин.

Comment: я не совсем еще понял эту математику... но что то ваша часть кода не совсем правильно работает... 
я вот написал координаты...
GLfloat vertices [] {
    100, 100, 0.0f,
    150, 50, 0.0f,
    50, 50, 0.0f
};
как бы треугольник из 480 пикселей должен на 50 быть выше! а он где то на потолке))

Comment: есть что почитать по поводу этих диапазонов? я их не совсем понимаю... допустим еще можно понять если окно квадратное! а если оно прямоугольное? или это и есть процентное соотношение??? типа если ширина 640 то я называю 1? а если мне нужно ширина 0 то указываю -1?

Comment: так же и с высотой?

Comment: @ИльяДударь Илья лично по мне,  тебе дали ответ в комментариях . я как понял суть вопроса `перевод из стандартного диапазона в свой собственный диапазон` . Рисовать по другому он как раз ни не должен .